# Yii 2.* highcharts динамические графики

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, highcharts

Хочу отображать на yii 2 графики их базы. Нашел дополнение http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-highcharts-widget.

Вопрос в следующем - как динамически обновлять графики с определенным интервалом?

Писать таймер на js? И вот тут загвоздка еще одна - пусть в первый запуск отображаются все данные за смену (с 8 до 20). ну а затем логично догружать только дополнительные значения. писать в массив в первый раз, а потом при каждой итерации проверять не пуст ли массив, брать максимальное время и делать запрос к базе?

Answer (score 2):

Если объем пересылаемых данных небольшой, то при каждом ajax-запросе можно возвращать всю необходимую информацию, а не порцию доп. значений.

Просто в реализации и поддержке.

Comment: 15к значений это много или мало7

Comment: 15k на каждом запросе - это очень много. 

С другой стороны зачем столько значений на графике?